# AngularJS and JSON with multiline string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have organised my data in JSON file, which contains multi-line string, separated in the array.
Like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "1. Some Name",
        "id": "1",
        "description": [
            "Some long text 1 ",
            "Some long text 2 "
       ]
    },
    {
        "name": "2. Some Name",
        "id": "2",
        "description": [
            "Some long text 1 ",
            "Some long text 2 "
        ]
    }
]
```

Then in my view I want show text in description:

```
<ion-view view-title="">
<ion-content>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap" 
             ng-repeat="rule in rules | filter: { id: whichid }">
            {{ rule.description }}
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

And my output look like this:

```
["Some long text 1","Some long text 2"]
```

How I can remove (or filter) that character '[' , '"' and ','?

Or if i use ng-bind-html="rule.description" directive i got:

```
Some long text 1 ,Some long text 2
```

Basically that is fine output, but they contain a comma ',' (which is in the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try Array.join() method.

Link: [Array.join()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

In your case: {{ rule.description.join(' ') }}

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
 <div class="item item-text-wrap" 
         ng-repeat="rule in rules | filter: { id: whichid }">
        <span ng-repeat="d in rule.description">{{ d }}</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This gave me a lot of grief as well. However I solved it with a custom pipe. 
Do the research on making a pipe, but this should help:

**pipes/arraytextfix/arraytextfix.ts (pipe file):**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the ArraytextfixPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'arraytextfix',
})

export class ArraytextfixPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * This is a very important pipe, as it removes a joining
   * comma, as outlined on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557436/angularjs-and-json-with-multiline-string
   */


  transform(value) { 
    value = value.join(' ');     
    return value
  } 
}
```

The other important thing, was adding that pipe file to the module of the file that you need to use it in.

For example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProjectsPage } from './projects'; 
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core'; // For translations to work
import { ArraytextfixPipe } from "../../pipes/arraytextfix/arraytextfix" // ADD THIS

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProjectsPage,
    ArraytextfixPipe // ADD THIS
  ],
  imports: [

    TranslateModule, // For translations to work
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ProjectsPage),
  ],
})
export class ProjectsPageModule {}
```

Then, (for me) you can then all the data in similar fashion, even using the translate pipe as well:

```
  <p [innerHTML]="'PROJECTS.BODY' | translate | arraytextfix"></p>
```

And this is basically my i18n/en.json data feed :

```
{
"PROJECTS": 
  {
    "HEADING": "Projects",
    "DESCRIPTION": "A default description",
    "BODY": ["bodytext line 1 <p>even has support for a paragraph</p>",
    "<p>Works well on line 2</p>",
    "line 3"]
  } 
}
```

I hope it helps a little